# Nodejs Express text file upload, no multer, busboy, or any other npm

Tags: node.js

I have a multi-line text file that I want to receive in my nodejs app via an http post.

I do not want to send multipart form data, I do not want to use extra packages such as multer or busboy or express-fileupload. Just the absolute basic file upload. Preserving newlines.

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const app = express()

app.post('/postTextFile', function(req, res, next) {
...
})

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(5002,'localhost')
```

I am sending like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --d @./test.txt http://localhost:5002/postTextFile
```

File is:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read the data directly.

Your node server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

app.post('/postTextFile', function(req, res, next) {
   let data = '';
   req.on('data', function(chunk) { data += chunk; });
   req.on('end', function() {
       console.log(data);
       res.sendStatus(200);
   });
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(5002, 'localhost');
```

Your request (use `--data-binary` to preserve multi-lines):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary "@./test.txt" http://localhost:5002/postTextFile
```

On the server, you get:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// send like this:
//
// curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary @./test.txt http://localhost:5002/postTextFile
//

const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const app = express()

app.post('/postTextFile', function(req, res, next) {
  let data = ""
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function(){
    console.log("("+data+")") 
  });
})

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(5002,'localhost')
```